# Cannot access Cakephp index.html file

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Hello I have a system with Ubuntu 14.04 32bit in which xampp version 7(latest) is installed and I have extracted Cakephp v3 folder in my document root folder. Whenever I access `localhost/cakephp` in the browser

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. `Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3` But when i enter `localhost/cakphp/index.php` the browser displays the the cake PHP page.

Comment: Are you sure you have there is no typo, because you said when you write `localhost/cakephp` it gives an error but `localhost/cakphp/index.php` displays the cake PHP page. Just make sure if the folder you extracted it in is named `cakephp` or `cakphp`

Comment: Folder name is correct and the problem is solved i download cakephp 3.3.11 and its done .